# First argument should convert to a variable and execute

Tags: bash

I have declared `arg="echo demo"`

When we execute the command `my_command arg`, then `arg` should be converted to `$arg` and should be executed like

```bsh
my_command () {
    $arg
}
```

How do I call `$1` as a variable?

Comment: Isn't what you have declared `arg="echo demo"` is a variable ?

Comment: There is no way for your function to work correctly with quoted strings. Assigning a command to a string is probably the wrong thing to want to do anyway. Probably see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

The `eval` shell built-in does what you want:

```
$ help eval
eval: eval [arg ...]
    Execute arguments as a shell command.

    Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the shell,
    and execute the resulting commands.
```

So your function could look like this:

```
my_command() {
    eval $1
}
```

Instead of `$1` you could also put `$*` and `my_command` will take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Note that by then `my_command` is little less than an alias for `eval`, so you could as well do:

```
alias my_command=eval
```